# Arxiv Equation Referencing Problem

Tags: cross-referencing, texlive, arxiv

I am struggling to submit my work on Arxiv. Even though referencing citations works, referencing to the equations within my tex file does not work. It results in (??).

I checked all the Arxiv help page suggestions, nothing helps.

I just use

```
\begin{align}\label{aa}
\begin{array}{lll}
\text{anything here}
\end{array}
\end{align}
```

and the result is still the same.

I import `\documentclass[]{interact}` which is the LaTeX temple of Taylor & Francis, given [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/taylor-and-francis-latex-template-for-authors-interact-layout-plus-apa-reference-style/jqhskrsqqzfz).

The errors I have from Arxiv is available [here](https://openload.co/f/z8dRz_TEIKA/Errors.txt).

I would appreciate any help and idea.

Comment: Reading the `.log` file, it is very eminent that LaTeX fails to find the graphics file `Turnover_costs_over_time'` and stops compilation very early (at line 360+x) and as such there is no change to write the label information, so no wonder `\ref{aa}` results in `??` You seem to have an outdated TL distribution (TL 2016) as well... we're heading towards `TL 2019` in a few months...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I don't think it is due to the turnover costs image. Because, my file is being compiled and the final PDF is just what I have on my local Tex platform. The only issue is that the equations are referred as ??

Comment: You should explain then, why LaTeX reports the missing file and performs an emergency stop on compilation ;-)

Comment: I added `.png' at the end. Now I don't get that warning but still have the ?? equation reference :(

Comment: Have you tried any other "classic" document class like `article` or `memoir` to find the source of the problem? Have you tried to turn off arxiv's hypertex through `00README.XXX` file?

Comment: ignoring hypertex with 00README.XXX worked likoe a magic! Can you please write this as an answer such that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes#nohypertex:

> By default, our TeX system uses HyperTeX to add hyperlinks between references, sections and equations within your paper. These show up in the PDF (and in the PostScript with some viewers).
>
> HyperTeX conflicts with a few style and class files. If you think this is a problem, you can disable HyperTeX for your submission by including a file `00README.XXX`. It should contain the line:
>
> ```
> nohypertex
> ```
>
> Note that HyperTeX changes the way citations appear in some styles — ranges will be represented as [11, 12, 13] instead of [11–13]. This is necessary for HyperTeX to be able to make individual links to each citation.

More information about `00README.XXX` available at https://arxiv.org/help/00README. Just a little quote from it:

> The `00README.XXX` file is read line-by-line before files are processed by AutoTeX. The order of lines is unimportant.
>
> ```
> nohypertex
> ```
>
> This stops any attempt by arXiv to automatically augment a paper with hyperlinks. However, it does not affect any facilities explicitly used within the paper's source.